Reviving MacBook 8,1 with Fedora 40: Built-in keyboard and mouse not working after driver installation attempt
I am trying to revive an old MacBook 8,1 A1534 and have installed Fedora Workstation 40. However, the built-in keyboard and mouse are not working. After some Google searching and trying to use the Roadrunner2 MacBook12-SPI-Driver. I am struggling to get it to work.
I am a bit of a Linux noob, so apologies. I have followed the instructions, yet when I try and run sudo dkms install -m apple_spi -v 0.1, and I get an output of:
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.8.5-301.fc40.x86_64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/apple_spi/0.1/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
Building module(s)....(bad exit status: 2)
Failed command:
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.5-301.fc40.x86_64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.5-301.fc40.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/apple_spi/0.1/build/make.log for more information.

I have used the following command sudo dnf kernel-devel-$(uname -r) to install the kernel-devel as found in another OP's post and rebooted and tried again, but to no avail.
The command uname -r returns 6.8.5-301.fc40.x86_64
Can anyone help me with the steps to resolve this? I love this little MacBook and don't want it to become e-waste. Thank you in advance 
